# JackRabbit how to find out the home directory in system

Tags: java, jackrabbit

***Good Morning,I need to do one requirement. i.e. Pragramatically(Java) i have to find out where the JackRabbit software Home Directory is available in the system with out scanning the total system***

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Jayaram.

Comment: please provide a link to the JackRabbit software

Comment: Hi you can try it with Apache Tomcat Software,if it is working with Tomcat then the same code will be work with the JackRabbit Software also.Please provide me the solution to find out Jackrabbit with out scanning the total system.